# Increase price by __ %

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have this e-commerce site, around 300 products. I came to this situation, where I need to increase the prices for all products if customers decides to buy a product on credit, let say 12 month. So the prices, for this situation, need to be increased by 5%. This price needs to be shown on view page? How can be this done.

For example, on my price.phtml file I use this formula to show the discount in price, not percentage.

```
                        <li><?php // Discount percents output start ?>
<?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
<?php 
$_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price) * 100); 
$_saveAmount = number_format(($_price - $_finalPrice), 2);  
?>
    <p class="special-price yousave">
            <span class="save-amount">-<?php echo $_saveAmount; ?> KM<br/>
            <span class="save-text">ušteda</span>
            </span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*** updated ***
with the following code I'm able to display final price:

```
echo number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(), '2', '.', ',')
```

is there I way to simply increase the final prices by 5%, and show it.

something like: (but this is not working)

```
echo number_format(($_product->getFinalPrice(), '2', '.', ',') * 1.05)
```

Comment: i figured it out: here is the code:

 echo number_format((($_product->getFinalPrice() * 1.25) / 12), '2', '.', ',')

Comment: Does it maintain that value when you add to cart? Also please add your comment as an answer and accept it when you can.

Comment: did not try this, and don't know if it maintains.